# Is there a difference between "throw(e)" and "throw e" in typescript?

Tags: typescript, exception

I couldn't find any information regarding the throwing syntax in typescript, so I am just wondering if those two are semantically identical? From what I've tested both methods keep the callstack.

```
try {
    throw new Error("You can't recover from this.");
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    throw e;
}
try {
    throw new Error("You can't recover from this.");
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    throw(e);
}
```

Doing it that way in C# would stomp the callstack, so I just want to be absolutely sure. The proper C# way is this:

```
try {
    throw new Exception("You can't recover from this.");
catch (Exception e)
    _logger.LogError(e);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning : It is conventional to `throw new Error(message)` 

Comment: The IT world seems quite small sometimes, I have just [read one of your articles](https://medium.com/@basarat/null-vs-undefined-in-typescript-land-dc0c7a5f240a) and now see your comment below my most recent question.
Do you mean instead of rethrowing like I do, I should just wrap the exceptions' error message?

Comment: Was talking about original throws. To summarise: Original-throw `throw new Error(message)`. Re-throw `throw e` 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`throw` in TypeScript (and in javascript) can throw arbitrary expression. Unlike `if`, `while` and `for`, `throw` can be followed by the expression immediately, without surrounding the expression in `()`.

From the expression semantic point of view, these two expressions are identical:

```
e
```

and

```
(e)
```

Comment: such a simple answer, I'm really wondering how I couldn't see that. I have already thrown plain strings...